# Android installer can't find hard drive in VMWare ESXI

Tags: android, esxi

When installing Android x86 I get the error "there is no hard drive to edit".

Googling the error only gives me two results, neither of which are very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the existing SCSI hard drive and add a IDE one.

Comment: While this might be a valid answer (no idea if it is!), a little more detail would not hurt.

Comment: @Hennes 1. Go into Settings of that VM.  2. Delete the existing SCSI (or other non-IDE) HDD that you have configured. 3. Add a new HDD  4. Expand the Advanced section (click the arrow, if ESX 6).  5. Ensure the "Virtual Device Node" is set to one of the IDE controllers.

Comment: Oh, I know hwo it is done, but I have no ESXi atm and I was hoping that the OP would expand and add screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

From [official documentation](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/installhowto):

> Issues
>
> VMware
>
> You have to change your virtual disk type to be IDE because the
> default type in VMware is SCSI, and Android-x86 kernel is not
> configured to support SCSI. You can follow these steps:
>
> - Create a virtual machine.
> - Edit virtual machine settings after the virtual machine created.
> - Choose the hard disk and remove it.
> - Add a hard disk to create a new virtual disk, then you can choose IDE as your virtual disk type.
> - When finished, you can install android-x86 normally.